# How to find the candle has day high / low in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

how to find the candle which has day high and the same way day low?

I am using 5 mins chart, I want to draw a trend line automatically. but I need to find the candle has day high and the candle has day low.. is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables on D timeframe

`[ dayOpen , dayHigh , dayLow , dayClose] = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [open,high,low,close], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)`